# how to access request's headers using minitest with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, minitest

I have the following test environment configuration

```rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/rails'

# Consider setting MT_NO_EXPECTATIONS to not add expectations to Object.
# ENV["MT_NO_EXPECTATIONS"] = true

Dir[Rails.root.join('test/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  # parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

and the following test

```rb
describe Abi::OrganizationsController do
  before do
    @request.headers['x-abi-token'] = 'test'
  end

  describe '#create' do
    let(:credit_rating) { 'A' }
    let(:organization_data) do
      {
        organization: {
          name: 'Test Organization',
          ....
    end

    it 'should return an organization id' do
      post(abi_organizations_path, params: organization_data)
    end
  end
end
```

the test was working perfectly fine until the need for sending a new header appeared.

I tried using `@request.headers` but at this point, `@request` is `nil`, and nothing I tried actually helped.

I managed to get the `@request` value when I updated the class to this

```rb
class Abi::OrganizationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
```

but then, I had to change the subject to this:

```rb
post :create, params: organization_data # <-- new subject
# post(abi_organizations_path, params: organization_data)
```

which is something I didn't want to do and then I started seeing this error

```
RuntimeError Exception: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
```

I'm kinda lost, I didn't find anything helpful on the internet and I feel like I'm the only one with this problem which doesn't make any sense.

Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from this sanity check in Rails.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18707ab17fa492eb25ad2e8f9818a320dc20b823/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L629-L637

My best bet is that your test class name does not match any controller name. Your test class is called `Abi::OrganizationsControllerTest` so Rails will assume a controller class like `Abi::OrganizationsController`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18707ab17fa492eb25ad2e8f9818a320dc20b823/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/constant_lookup.rb#L36

Comment: I triple-check that and the class name matches. That's why I'm bugging my mind over this

Comment: Add some puts in the rails code for instance with `bundle open active_support`

Comment: I got the error: `@request` is only available AFTER the request is made, according to the docs. It is not possible to do what I want here. I will accept the answer anyway because I learned something new today. Thanks!